# How to assign clusters to new observations (test data) using hierchical clustering?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage,fcluster
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
np.random.seed(4711)  # for repeatability of this tutorial
a = np.random.multivariate_normal([10, 0], [[3, 1], [1, 4]], size=[100,])
b = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 20], [[3, 1], [1, 4]], size=[50,])
X = np.concatenate((a, b),)

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1])
```

[image]

```
# fit clusters
Z = linkage(X, method='ward', metric='euclidean', preserve_input=True)

# plot dendrogram
```

[image]

```
max_d = 50
clusters = fcluster(Z, max_d, criterion='distance')

# now if I have new data
a = np.random.multivariate_normal([10, 0], [[3, 1], [1, 4]], size=[10,])
b = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 20], [[3, 1], [1, 4]], size=[5,])
X_test = np.concatenate((a, b),)
print(X_test.shape)  # 150 samples with 2 dimensions
plt.scatter(X_test[:,0], X_test[:,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

how to compute distances for the new data and assign clusters using clusters from training data?

code references: [joernhees.de](https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/08/26/scipy-hierarchical-clustering-and-dendrogram-tutorial/)

Answer (score 8):

### You don't.

Clustering does not have training and test stages. It is an *explorative* approach. You explore your data, and you can also explore your new data by **rerunning the algorithm**. But by the very nature of this algorithm **you cannot meaningfully "assign" new data to the old structure** because this data could completely change the discovered structure.

### If you want classification, use a classifier.

Clustering algorithms are *not* substitutes for classifiers. If you want to classify new instances, use a classifier, and use e.g. this workflow:

1. Explore the data with clustering (many times)
2. Label the training data with the clusters your domain expert deems meaningful (validate the clstering!)
3. Train a classifier
4. Use the classifier to label new instances the same way

There are, of course, some exceptions. In k-means and Ward (but not e.g. in single-link) the nearest-centroid-classifier *can* somewhat apply the discovered model directly to new data. Still, this means "converting" the clustering into a static classifier, and the result may *no longer be a local optimum* on the full data set (see also: concept drift)

Comment: If I want to apply different sets of models to each cluster, would it be meaningful to use distance metric(say euclidean) to assign clusters to new data, and use the fitted models for prediction?

Comment: What about outliers? The example you had above is too simplistic.

Comment: This isn't defended very well. You should provide some evidence that assigning new data invalidates the original model. There is nothing in classification that would add a stronger guarantee. New data can change the assumed distributions of any supervised model as well. You shouldn't say "You Don't" ... that's too simplistic. There are libraries that allow you to predict the cluster assignment of new data and they exist for a reason.

Comment: It works for k-means, but there are many many many more algorithms that cannot predict, for many reasons. Consider DBSCAN, Affinity Propagation, Spectral Clustering.

Comment: The whole purpose of doing clustering is to find new features that can be identified for supervised learning. I think the first paragraph should be corrected

Comment: No, the main purpose of clustering is for a *human* to understand the data better. It is an EDA technique. The results usually are not quite good enough on real data to use them as features.

Comment: please don't presume to know what we're using the clustering for.  perhaps we're trying to do something creative you haven't considered yet.  in the meanwhile, the question isn't answered.